# Issue while forming regex string in a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run the below query in a stored procedure and its not working.
We tried to print the query using NOTICE and we saw E gets appended to the regex and thats the reason the query doesnt show any output.

**Not working**

```
select order,version from mytable
where substring(version  from quote_literal('[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}'))
IN ('6.2') and order= 'ABC';
```

But the same query if i run from pgadmin query tool, it works fine.

**Working**

```
select order,version  from mytable
where substring(version from '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}')
IN ('6.2') and order= 'ABC';
```

My requirement is to form the reqex dynamically in the stored procedure. Please guide on how to achieve this.

Below is the line of code in my stored procedure,

```
sql_query = sql_query || ' AND substring(version from ' || quote_literal( '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}' ) || ') IN (' || quote_literal(compatibleVersions) || ')';
raise notice 'Value: %', sql_query;                                        
EXECUTE sql_query  INTO query_result ;
```

and from notice i am getting the below output,

```
AND substring(version from E'[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{1}') IN ('{6.2}')
```

My requirement is to make this regex work.

I narrowed down to this query,

**working**

```
select substring(version from '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}') from mytable ;
```

**not working**

```
select substring(version from quote_literal('[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}')) from mytable ;
```

Now i think its easy to fix it. You can try at your end also running this above queries.

Comment: `quote_literal()` is only needed in dynamic SQL. You don't need it in static SQL. So just use the working version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i intended to form the query dynamically inside the stored procedure by appending dynamic where conditions.

Comment: If I see that correctly, [0-9]{1} is the same as [0-9]. Also, you can use \d as a shorthand for [0-9]. See [this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) in Table 9-17.

Comment: What's wrong with using a string constant that starts with `E`? I guess you should show some of the failing code.

Comment: **[edit]** your question. Do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: Hm, the `E` should be no problem. Are you sure that your problem is not the `'{6.2}'`?

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe .. You are amazing. You are right. {6.2} is the problem as IN accepts string seperated by comma.  **IN ('{6.2}') should be IN ('6.2')**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your problem is not really the extended string literal syntax using `E`, but the string representation of the array in the `IN` list, your PL/pgSQL should look somewhat like this:

```
sql_query = sql_query ||
            ' AND substring(version from ' || quote_literal( '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}' ) ||
                ') IN (' || (SELECT string_agg(quote_literal(x), ', ')
                             FROM unnest(compatibleVersions
                            ) AS x(x)) || ')';
```

Answer (score 0):

quote_literal should be used in situations where u want to dynamically construct queries. In such situation quote_literal will be replaced by E in the final constructed query.

**right way to use**

```
select * from config_support_module where substring(firmware from '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}') IN ('6.2');


select * from config_support_module where substring(firmware from E'[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}') IN ('6.2') ;
```

**wrong usage of quote_literal in static queries**

```
select * from config_support_module where substring(firmware from quote_literal('[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}')) IN ('6.2') ;
 This doesnt give you any errors/output.
```

**quote_literal  usage in dynamic queries**

```
sql_query = sql_query || ' AND substring(version from ' || quote_literal( '[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}' ) || ') ... .. ...
```